# Is it an anti-pattern to use a class based react component in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am want to use a certain component in react native but all the third party components were written as class based components. Is it an anti-pattern to use a class based react component in a functional component? For example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import ClassComponent from 'SomeOldClassBasedCompont';

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
        <ClassComponent />
     </View>
      
  );
}
```

Comment: Not at all.....

Comment: In the latest version of reactjs, it is recommended to write your component in a function component because it is simpler and easier... But it does not mean you shouldn't use class-based component or you have to rewrite your class-based components or you shouldn't use class-based third party libraries. Class-based components and function-based components are totally compatible to each other. If your read this (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) you can read the sentence 'The above two components are equivalent from React’s point of view.' So it is not an anti-pattern at all.

Comment: Not at all an anti-pattern. A React component is a React component is a React component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class based`/`function base` components are a React Component at all.

Let's take an example:
Assume you have 2 different components, `FirstComponent` & `SecondComponent` and you want to use them inside an `App` component, what do you do?

```
export default function App() {

  const firstTitle = "just an example";
  const secondTitle = "another example";

  return (
    <View>
        <FirstComponent title={firstTitle}/>
        <SecondComponent  title={secondTitle}/>
     </View>
  );
}
```

> Is it matter for `App` component to render a functional or class-based component? is there any difference between rendering `FirstComponnet` or `SecondComponent`? what about passing props?

Since the component returns a valid JSX form, it will be rendered.

> So, what are the differences between functional and class-based components?

The differences are in syntax, the ways to manage the life cycles, using hooks, constructors, and the special value of `this`. in other words, the differences are in the component **definition** and not related or affected on the **parent** or **child** components.

##### Summary

components are components, no matter is written in a class-based or functional-based structure.